# Swift3: not the expected contextual result type NSArray

Tags: swift3, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I am migrating my code from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3. Before it was working fine after migrating I am facing not expected contextual result type NSArray
Here is my code

```
func setConfirmedBookingsAfterSorting() {
        if let bookings =  ContentService.sharedInstance.confirmedBookings {
            self.confirmedBookings = (bookings as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: true)])
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use Swift's native sort? `bookings.sort{ $0.startTime < $1.startTime }`

Answer (score 1):

The declared type of the method used is `func sortedArray(using sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> [Any]`, which means the result is implicitly converted to a Swift array.

Try this:

```
((bookings as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "startTime", ascending: true)])) as NSArray
```

This prevents the conversion and maintains the result as an `NSArray` Objective C object.

Comment: This looks decidedly more complicated than [Alexander's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476693/swift3-not-the-expected-contextual-result-type-nsarray#comment70159404_41476693): can you describe advantages?

Comment: @greybeard - it's a more minimal modification of the code in the question than the suggestion in the comment, which some people may prefer.  Specifically, it doesn't require changing the type of any declarations, and it doesn't change the behaviour from returning a sorted copy to an in-place sort.

Comment: @brimstone - the declared type of the method used is `func sortedArray(using sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]) -> [Any]`, which means the result is implicitly converted to a Swift array.  This prevents the conversion and maintains the result as an `NSArray` Objective C object.